# Plot New York neighborhoods with d3.js

Tags: d3.js, geolocation, maps

I am trying to create a New York neighborhoods map with d3.js.

I downloaded the file from here
https://www1.nyc.gov/site/planning/data-maps/open-data/dwn-nynta.page

Then I drop the shapefile into http://mapshaper.org/ and simplify it to 1%. Finally I export it as a topojson.

Now, I am using the following d3.js code and I get random lines.

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style type="text/css">
  body {
    font-family: arial, sans;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 40px auto;
  }
  .ny-neighborhoods {
    stroke: #000;
    stroke-width: .50;
    fill: none;
  }
</style>

<body>
<div id="chart-container"></div>
</body>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/queue-async/1.0.7/queue.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var margin = {top: 5, right: 5, bottom: 5, left: 5};
var width = 900 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

queue()
    //.defer(d3.csv, "sales.csv")
    .defer(d3.json, "nynta.json")
    .await(ready);

function ready(error, data, ny) {
  if (error) return console.warn(error);
  console.log(ny)
  //data.forEach(function(d) {
        //d.val = +d.val;
      //});
  var nyfeatures = topojson.feature(ny,ny.objects.nynta)
  console.log(nyfeatures)
  var svg = d3.select("#chart-container")
    .append("svg")
      .attr("class", "map")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
  var path = d3.geoPath()
      .projection(d3.geoAlbersUsa()
      .fitSize([width, height], nyfeatures));
  var nyPaths = svg.selectAll(".ny-neighborhoods")
      .data(nyfeatures.features)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", "ny-neighborhoods")
      .attr("d", function(d) { return path(d); })
}
</script>
```

Comment: can you share the sales.csv and nynta.json files that you work with?

Comment: I made the very same steps that you described, and it works smooth for me, the end result is fine, not as on the picture you inserted. Can you doublecheck the steps you made?

Comment: Really? Amazing - let me try again

Comment: ping me once you are finished, please

Comment: @elias I am getting the same issue still, I get the shapefile from the link, I simplify it with mapshaper to 1%, export it as a topojson "nynta.json". Then I use the code - I literally copy/pasted it from stackoverflow this time and when I run it in my local server I get those crazy lines. Did you use exactly the same code? I was thinking it could be relater to geoAlbersUsa?

Comment: I used the very same code. Can you maybe link your json file?

Comment: @elias you are right, it must be something with the json; to share it with you I created a gist https://gist.github.com/jeangelj/c1f28f3d77e092c761898ba1248e01ad and the json looks very weird ... did you also just drop it into mapshaper, simplify it and export it as topojson? (I am confused how I screwed that up)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136478/discussion-between-elias-and-jeangelj).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the amazing effort and time investment of @elias, we figured out that the shapefile didn't work. Instead we used the geojson and simplified that in mapshaper.org to export it as a topojson.

One hint for future usage - when you do that, you probably will save it under a new filename, so it will change your features hierarchy

```
var nyfeatures = topojson.feature(ny,ny.objects.newyork)
```

Thank You very much, it looks now like this:

[image]